# Jump to the second ViewController, the IBOutlet UIWebView in it is not inital

Tags: swift, uiwebview

In the first viewController's `viewDidAppear` method, I jump to the second viewController using:

```
self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the second viewController, the IBOutlet webview is always nil when I invoke it in the viewDidLoad function. I am sure the IBOutlet is connect correctly.
My English is not good. I hope I described the problem well. Thanks for you anwsers!

Comment: Did you create `secondViewController` from storyboard?

Comment: Yes,I do.If I set secondViewController as default (the start view controller), the webView can display correctly.

Comment: Can you show the code that you initialize `secondViewController` ?

Comment: import UIKit

    class AutherPageViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var authWebView: UIWebView!
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let urlstring = "http://www.baidu.com"
           let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            authWebView.loadRequest(request)
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
    }

Comment: Not this one. The code before you write `self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` is I am asking.

Comment: var secondViewController: SecondViewController {
        get{
            let svc = SecondViewController()
            return svc
        }
    }

Comment: I will write answer in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `svc`without storyboard. That's why your `webView` becomes `nil`. You need to initialize it from storyboard. For this you need to give a storyboard id to `SecondViewController` in storyboard. Like this:

[image]

Now you can instantiate it like this code:

```
var secondViewController: SecondViewController {
    return self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("second") as SecondViewController
}
```